# Grabbing information between 2 dates in php

Tags: php

I have an array that looks something like this

```
$data =
        [
            [
                'date' => '2020-10-01',
                'product' => 'Product 1',
                'description' => 'Product 1',
            ],
            [
                'date' => '2020-11-01',
                'product' => 'Product 2',
                'description' => 'Product 2',
            ],
            [
                'date' => '2020-12-01',
                'product' => 'Product 3',
                'description' => 'Product 3',
            ],
            [
                'date' => '2021-01-01',
                'product' => 'Product 4',
                'description' => 'Product 4',
            ]
        ];
```

And what I would like to do is grab all the information between 2 dates.
For example I want everything between 2021-01-01 and 2020-11-01 and it would then display Product 2, Product 3 and Product 4

I'm not sure how to go about this

Comment: You write a loop, inside it you test the dates, etc etc

Comment: What do you mean by "between 2 dates"? Do you want to look at the actual dates, so if an entry contains a date between your two dates then it should be used, or do you look only at the array, and only use entries which are between two selected array entries? Is the array sorted?

Comment: And if this data comes from a database, the simplest solution sould be to amend the query to match your requirement

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$data =
        [
            [
                'date' => '2020-10-01',
                'product' => 'Product 1',
                'description' => 'Product 1',
            ],
            [
                'date' => '2020-11-01',
                'product' => 'Product 2',
                'description' => 'Product 2',
            ],
            [
                'date' => '2020-12-01',
                'product' => 'Product 3',
                'description' => 'Product 3',
            ],
            [
                'date' => '2021-01-01',
                'product' => 'Product 4',
                'description' => 'Product 4',
            ]
        ];
        
$from = new DateTime('2020-11-11');
$to = new DateTime('2030-10-13');
        
foreach ($data as $d){
    $productDate = new DateTime($d['date']);
    if (($productDate >= $from) && ($productDate <= $to)){
        echo "is between";
        var_dump($d);
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Yea, I didnt realise you had changed the Start and End date from the ones used in the question for some reason :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to do this in PHP you can create a similar function to SQL's WHERE ... [BETWEEN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between/) ... AND ... using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#refsect1-function.array-filter-description).

If you have access to the SQL query then probably you want to have the DBMS take care of this as @RiggsFolly mentioned in the comments.

```
$lowerBound = strtotime('2020-11-01');
$upperBound = strtotime('2021-01-01');

$result = array_filter($data, function ($item) use ($lowerBound, $upperBound) {
    $itemDate = strtotime($item['date']); 

    return $lowerBound <= $itemDate && $itemDate <= $upperBound;
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Hope you dont mind, just thought I would save a few CPU Cycles

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments if the data is originally sourced from a database query it's a much better idea to limit the content there, for example:

```
// SQL query to be used in a prepared statement

SELECT date, product, description
FROM products 
WHERE date >= ?
    AND date <= ?
```

However, failing that, the key thing here is that the dates are all properly formatted: `timetamps` follow the pattern `Y-m-d` which means that both the chronological and alphabetical order are the same

```
Generally...
    Start        ===>   End
    A            ===>   Z
    1            ===>   10
    0000-00-00   ===>   9999-99-99

Which means...
    2020-12-30 < 2020-12-31 < 2021-01-01
```

That being the case when we compare two properly formatted dates (in the same format) we have no need to alter the data type/format; converting the string with `DateTime` or `strtotime` adds nothing except `~10x` the required time compared to comparing the values in string format.

Anyway, comparing the dates:

**Using `array_filter`**

```
$minDate = '2020-11-01';
$maxDate = '2021-01-01';
$result  = array_filter($data, function ($item) use ($minDate, $maxDate) {
    return $minDate <= $item["date"] && $item["date"] <= $maxDate;
});
```

**Using `foreach`**

```
$minDate = '2020-11-01';
$maxDate = '2021-01-01';
$result  = [];

foreach($data as $item){
    if($minDate <= $item["date"] && $item["date"] <= $maxDate){
        $result[] = $item;
    }
}
```